# Get distinct values and sum their respective quantities

Tags: sql

I have a problem.
I have a result query with order numbers item numbers and different quantities for each item.
I want to distinct all item numbers and count all quantities for each specific item number.

Here is an example table (Query output):

```
|  OrderNo  |  ItemNo  |  Qty  |
--------------------------------
|  XY123    |  3000    |  4    |
|  XY123    |  2000    |  2    |
|  ZZ999    |  3000    |  6    |
|  ZZ999    |  1000    |  3    |
|  PP333    |  1000    |  5    |
```

The distinct values for all sold items with their item numbers would be:

```
1000 -> Count/Sum the Qty
2000 -> Count/Sum the Qty
3000 -> Count/Sum the Qty
```

Result:

```
|  ItemNo  |  QtyTotal  |
-------------------------
|  1000    |   8        |
|  2000    |   2        |
|  3000    |   10       |
```

My problem is, when I DISTINCT the ItemNo, i dont know how to SUM their corresponding quantities before. I need some advice please.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: I use both. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by`:

```
select ItemNo, sum(Qty) as QtyTotal
from QueryOutput q
group by ItemNo;
```

You can replace QueryOutput with a query that produces your *example table*.

[Fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71452485/get-distinct-values-and-sum-their-respective-quantities/71452516#71452516)

Comment: Thank you very much! Although I used GROUP BY before, I just forgot the SUM(Qty) within the select statement.